# stix font error: PK font stix-mathrm could not be created

Tags: fonts, errors, stix

I can't compile the document with stix font.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
    Package stix.
    \[y=X\beta+\varepsilon\]
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
miktex-makemf: The stix-mathrm source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk

: PK font stix-mathrm could not be created.

Process exited with error(s)
```

Any help?

Comment: You might have updated `stix.sty` without having done so with the fonts. MiKTeX is particularly known for not updating font maps.

Comment: They are opentype fonts, hence require compiling with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, and loading `fontspec`. If you want to compile with `pdfLaTeX` you can load `esstix` (a type 1 version of the fonts and the necessary files to use them in LaTeX).